# Iptables: dropping/rejecting new and invalid connections

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I'm very new to iptables and my goal is the block `NEW` and `INVALID` connections on the `INCOMING` chain and log any attempts for a `NEW` connection.

I'm also letting any and all traffic out on the `OUTGOING` chain.

This is what I did:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,INVALID -j LOG
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,INVALID -j DROP
```

When I add the last line I can no longer get out on the web.

My current setup is an old Macbook Air bridged with a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  The Air will eventually serve as my firewall between my router connecting to the Internet and my internal network once I get the iptables working correctly.